# Calling Methods Names from a List of Strings

Tags: java, string, list, maps

I have a string as such:

```
String[] names = new String[] {"FirstMethod", "SecondMethod"...} //200 of these
```

At the moment I have to type in manually:

```
public void onSuccess( Map<String,ControlService.RegisterValues> result ) {

    for( String Name : result.keySet() ){

        message+=result.get(Name).FirstMethod+", ";
        message+=result.get(Name).SecondMethod+", ";
        //I call the method here - I'd like to use the list above to call it in though
```

Obviously I don't want to be typing out 200 times, is there a way I can use this list, convert it into a method name, and loop over that?

EDIT:

Class I'm calling it from:

```
public interface ControlService extends RemoteJsonService
{

public void I2CRegisterValues( String [] Names, AsyncCallback<Map<String,RegisterValues>> callback); 

public class RegisterValues
{
    int FirstMethod;
    //etc.
```

Comment: `result.get(Name).FirstMethod` is an access of a _field_, not a method. Did you mean `result.get(Name).FirstMethod()`?

Comment: You want to invoke method or get the value of a field in the result.get(Name) object?

Comment: haha well it comes up with a blue triangle on Eclipse - so I figured it was a method. I'll edit the above with the class I'm calling it from

Comment: The result of "result.get(Name)" is an instance of type ControlService.RegisterValues. Does this type really declare so many methods? Or could the names array contain many equal method names? But, nevertheless, what you are trying can be achieved via reflection.

Comment: I've added the method I'm calling it from. Sorry, I'm not too good with jargon (at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a method using [`Class.getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29), which returns a [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) object. You then invoke that `Method` object by passing it the instance and arguments:

```
method.invoke(result.get(Name), whateverArguments);
```

Your question was a bit ambiguous as to whether you're really accessing a *field*. If that's the case, you can get a [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) via [`Class.getField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29), and get its value via the `get` method, again passing in the instance on which you want to get the field.

In either case, the result is typed as `Object`, and you need to downcast that to the expected type. In the case of a primitive like `int`, the object returned will be a boxed type like `Integer`, which you can auto-unbox to `int`:

```
int foo = (Integer) method.invoke(...);
```

The whole thing would look something like:

```
Field field = I2CRegisterValues.getField(fieldName);
Object o = field.get(result.get(Name));
int fieldValue = (Integer) o;
```

... where `fieldName` is a `String` variable in a loop of your `String[] names`. You can also do the above as a one-liner:

```
int fieldValue = (Integer) I2CRegisterValues
    .getField(fieldName)
    .get(result.get(Name));
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out the syntax for getting the field out of the method. I tried `result.get(Name).getField()` and `result.getField()`

Comment: And the result is typed out as an integer in the first place, I edited the question with the new field in

Comment: I updated my answer to show how it'd all fit together. Btw, you should look into Java naming conventions; the code you posted doesn't follow the standard conventions. Variables (including fields) should start with lowercase letters (`firstMethod` instead of `FirstMethod`, `name` instead of `Name`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Class.getMethod(methodName).invoke(....);
```

See the API for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
     //load desired Class at runtime
  Class classObj = Class.forName("xyz.abc.YourClassName");
  Object obj = classObj .newInstance();

 //invoke specific method at runtime
     for( String methodName : result.keySet() ){
       Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName , noparams);
       method.invoke(obj, null);
      }
```